# Nested CSS: How to get to the child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following section of code. I'm trying to style all three "one-third" classed divs without styling all the one-third classes on the site. I thought to use a nested style. I've tried various combinations of ids and classes, both with and without the '>', but am striking out.

The last style I tried was:

```
<style>
    .widget_service > .container > .column > .one-third {
          background-color: #ececec !important;
    }
</style>
```

FAIL.

```
<section id="ultimate_service_widget-2" class="widget widget_service">
    <div class="container clearfix">
         <div class="column display-center clearfix">
              <div class="one-third"></div>
              <div class="one-third"></div>
              <div class="one-third clearfix-half"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which of the one-third divs *do* you want to select?

Comment: You could try using [nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Comment: isn't there something wrong in the question ? You want **one-third** without affecting **one-third** ? but which third???

Comment: Edited to clarify. I want all one-thirds on this page, but not all one-thirds on the site.

Comment: Where are the other `one-third` classes on the site?

Comment: @gaynorvader They could be anywhere. All pages share the same stylesheet though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current selector selects any direct children of your `.column` element. With this, that matches all three `.one-third` elements.

If you want to match:

1. The first child: `.one-third:first-child` or `.one-third:nth-child(1)`.
2. The second child: `.one-third:nth-child(2)`.
3. The last child: `.one-third:last-child` or `.one-third:nth-child(3)`.

Comment: I thought so too, but it's not changing the background-color of any of them.

Comment: @Goob is there anything contained within these `.one-third` elements? If not they may have a computed height of `0px`, meaning they'd not be visible.

Comment: Yes, there is text in each one.

Comment: @Goob must be caused by something you haven't provided here. Here is a JSFiddle demo showing your code combined with the selectors in my answer working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qn72opw8.

Comment: I see on the site that the ">" is getting converted to "&gt;". Interesting - that would be why it's not working.

Comment: @Goob sounds like you need to use a different editing program. Things should never be automatically converted into HTML entities whilst inside `style` tags!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which nth element of class `one-third` you want to select:

`.widget_service > .container > .column > .one-third:nth-child(2) { }`

Above code will select second selector.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

Since ids should be unique you could just use:

```
#ultimate_service_widget-2 .one-third{
    background-color: #ececec;
}
```

You might need to be more specific if there are more `one-third` classes under the `ultimate_service_widget-2` id.